# Hibernate .getResultStream() not streaming?

Tags: hibernate, mysql-connector

I am trying to stream a lot of data from MySQL with Hibernate via `.getResultStream()` and I am getting OutOfMemoryErrors.

On the first row load after a while I will get this exception where I can see:

```
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1963) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar:5.1.37]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:3308) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar:5.1.37]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:463) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar:5.1.37]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:3032) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar:5.1.37]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2280) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar:5.1.37]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.37.jar:5.1.37]
```

what surprises me here is the `readAllResults` - this would seem it is not a real streaming.

I also tried to use:

```
query.setHint("org.hibernate.fetchSize", 1000)
```

With no effect.

I have then upgraded to MySQL Connector 8.0.19 and Hibernate 5.4.11.Final with the same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following applies only for Hibernate versions without [HHH-9340](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9340). Correct answer is the [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65715303/118846).

That is correct observation. Method `getResultStream` just views result list as a `Stream`. According [API documentation](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultStream--):

> By default this method delegates to getResultList().stream(), however
> persistence provider may choose to override this method to provide
> additional capabilities.

Hibernate has selected not to override this method, as can be seen from [QueryImpl](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/query/internal/QueryImpl.java) and classes it inherits from.

Comment: But also see org.hibernate.query.Query: `default Stream<R> getResultStream() { return stream(); }`

Comment: The answer is wrong, see the other answer from @Gokhan Oner!

Answer (score 6):

it's interesting that accepted answer is wrong. As mentioned by Mikko, JPA Spec leave the implementation to vendors & Hibernate actually implemented it, see [Query](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/602926bf9bd4eafa54771d22846eb02946cccd91/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/query/Query.java#L1139) class which QueryImpl implements.

Now, the reason is how MySQL behaves. As described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html), MySQL by default load all result to memory. You have 2 options, check here -> https://vladmihalcea.com/whats-new-in-jpa-2-2-stream-the-result-of-a-query-execution/

Basically, either set Statement fetch size to Integer.MIN_VALUE and then each record will be fetched one after the other, or set the useCursorFetch connection property to true and then you can set the Statement fetch size to a positive integer value ( or set defaultFetchSize connection property so you don't need to define for every query )

Comment: You could not be more right. Question refers to version 5.4.11, and that clearly includes changes made in [HHH-9340](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9340).